# Change binding from http to wsHttp - and now i can't connect to the server

Tags: wcf

this is my first WCF project. 
I define end point protocol of http - and i just change it to wshttp. 
I trying to connect to the server from the client ( that was connected to same server when it was http ) and i get message

"The service certificate is not provide. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredintials ... "

I dont know how to solve this problem

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to use "Update Service Reference". The client can't know that you made those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wsHttpbinding is secure by default and uses tranport\message security(don't remember exactly which one). Hence you are seeing this error. The server component (assuming IIS) needs to have a certificate installed and SSL enabled. Google around to find how to enable wshttpbinding on an endpoint.

Comment: It uses message based security by default though it can be turned off or switched to transport. This article here explains how http://www.nikgupta.net/2012/05/demystifying-wcf-and-ssl-part-1/